# VLOOKUP on CONCATENATE Values "#N/A" error

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm trying to use VLOOKUP to look for the values coming from the "Summary 2" sheet in excel, however, I keep on getting #N/A, I'm wondering if it's the format or something else. Thanks for the help.

I am using this formula to look for the values of Column F in the summary sheet.

`=VLOOKUP(F14,'Summary 2'!$A$2:$B$9,2,FALSE)`

[image]

[image]

Comment: You dont show the columns on sheet `QTY Take-off`, but assuming it is column F, maybe check for trailing spaces in both sheets

Comment: Yes sorry, it is column F. Column F is concatenated values, so I'm wondering if it has something to do with with.

Comment: It can be hard to troubleshoot. What I would do is copy and paste one of the values from "summary 2" into column F and then replace each part with one part of the concat formula, one picee at a time and see which part causes the problem. I would be wondering if there are two spaces somewhere, like between "Area" and "1"

Comment: Guaranteed, it will be something stupid :)

Comment: Thanks Dave, I see the problem now, the formula worked when I tried it on the first cell,

Answer (score 0):

```
=VLOOKUP(F14,'Summary 2'!A:B,2,0)
```

Here Excel performs a vertical lookup in the specified range ('Summary 2'!A:B) based on the value in cell F14. Here's a breakdown of the formula:

**F14:** This is the lookup value. It represents the member name for which you want to find the corresponding quantity.

**'Summary 2'!A:B:** This is the table array or range where the lookup will be performed. Column A contains the member names, and Column B contains the corresponding quantities. The lookup will be based on the values in Column A.

**2:** This argument specifies that the function should return the value from the second column of the range 'Summary 2'!A:B. In this case, it will return the quantity associated with the matched member name.

**0:** This is the range lookup parameter. A value of 0 (or FALSE) indicates an exact match. The function will only return a result if it finds an exact match for the member name in F14.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula looks correct, as you can see in my example:

[image]

As you can see, I'm using the same formula you are, and everything seems fine.
As you can see: if the value is found, the number is taken. If not, you see the `#N/A` error value.
One thing which might be useful, is the `=EXACT()` function you can use for checking if the value corresponds or not. Just a small difference can cause `=VLOOKUP()` to fail. I have the impression that your value "AREA 1, 1, BEAMS" (or something) is a formula result (most probably some concatenation or `=TEXTJOIN()` result). Again: `=EXACT()` can help you check your results.